# Check if element only contains another element without any text

Tags: jquery

E.g: a button only contains icon

```
<button><i>i</i> Foo</button> -- false

<button><i>i</i></button>  -- true

<button> <i>i</i> </button>  -- true
```

I've tried this so far - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxWgZL

```
$($(this).html()).is('i');

$.trim($($(this).html()).remove('i')));
```

Here's what I ended up with thanks to @veerasuthan V

```
$('button[title]').filter(function(){
    var children = $(this).children().context.childNodes;
    for(i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] && children[i]['nodeType'] == 3) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}).tooltip();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button").each(function(index,element){
    console.log($(this).children().context.childNodes);
    // here you can check if the array of element contains "text" element in it
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yex7k63b/1/)

```js
$('button').each(function() {

  // if this button has <i> children return true, otherwise false
  var check1 = ($(this).children('i').length > 0) ? true : false,

    // if the trimmed text of this button after filtering out the "i" text is empty
    // [means if it doesn't contain text other than the "i" in the icon] then return 
    // true, otherwise return false
    check2 = ($(this).text().replace('i', '').trim() === '') ? true : false,
    result = (check1 && check2) ? true : false;

  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>a</button> <!-- false -->
<button> <span>he</span> </button> <!-- false -->
<button><i>i</i> Foo</button> <!-- false -->
<button><i>i</i> </button> <!-- true -->
<button> <i>i</i></button> <!-- true -->
<button>sss</button><!-- false -->
```